# Is there a way to create, overwrite, or insert to a table using Snowflake stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My goal is to create a table using variables stored in another table. For example, my date references are all in one table, which I want to use to query and create and/or insert to another table.

Let's say I have my reference table  `db.schema.reference` and I want to create `db.schema.target` from the ff sources: `db.schema.sourceA` and `db.schema.sourceB`

I've created this stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure get_target()
returns text
langauge python
runtime_version = '3.8'
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
handler getTarget()
as
$$
def getTarget(session):
    dateRef=session.sql("select min(refDate) from db.schema.reference").collect()[0][0]
    endLkp=str(session.sql("select last_day(to_date('{}'))".format(dateRef))
    
    session.sql("""
    create table db.schema.target as
    with tblA as (
        select id, value as valueA 
        from db.schema.sourceA 
        where date between to_date('{dateRef}') and to_date('{endLkp}')
    ), tblB as (
        select id, value as valueB 
        from db.schema.sourceB 
        where date between to_date('{dateRef}') and to_date('{endLkp}')
    )
    select a.id, a.valueA, b.valueB
    from tblA as a left join tblB as b on a.id=b.id
    """)

    return 'succeeded'
$$;
```

When I try to call it by executing `call get_target();` it outputs 'succeeded' but the table `db.schema.target` does not exist.

Comment: Your SP will always return 'succeeded', regardless of what happens within the code,  because that's what you've coded it to do. I would suggest looking at SF's query history and seeing what is being run (or not run) - that should give you clues as to what the problem is. Otherwise, add proper error handling to your SP so that you capture any errors and return them rather than just returning 'succeeded'

Comment: In your Session.sql statement you are trying to run CREATE TABLE AS SELECT , there is no action collect method to this Session.sql, can you please try adding collect method to it